# drf use different serializer show 'You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want post question info first , and post options list with question id
at "opt_ser.save()" it show "'You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect \'serializer.validated_data\' instead. '"

```
class QuestionAddApiView(APIView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    option_list = request.data.pop('option_list')

    question_serializer = QuestionReadAndWriteSerializer(data=request.data)
    try:
        if question_serializer.is_valid():
            question_serializer.save()
            question = question_serializer.instance

            opt_response = []

            for option_item in option_list:
                option_item['question'] = question
                opt_ser = OptionSerializer(data=option_item)
                if opt_ser.is_valid():
                    opt_ser.save()
                    opt_response.append(opt_ser.data)
            question['option_list'] = opt_response
            return BResponse(question, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    except Exception as e:

        return BResponse(question_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `validated_data` instead of `data`.

This pattern of saving on object and creating its related objects is pretty common, and in DRF you can do these my overridong create of parent and handle creating child objects from there.

I suggest you override `create` menthod of `QuestionReadAndWriteSerializer`. you an follow the official docs, for [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)